# iOS objective C: custom sorting NSarray not default ascending/descending

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsarray, nssortdescriptor

I have a question regarding custom sorting of nsarray. I currently have an nasty sorted by a key(commandeState) that can take 3 values( 5,6,7). so far I can sort it ascending/descening like this:

```
NSSortDescriptor *descr =  [NSsortDescriptor] sortDescriptorwithKey: @"commandesState" ascending:NO];
```

What I want to achieve is having the nsarray sorted in this order 6,5,7. Can anyone help showing how I could achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the next series?, I hope you understand the meaning of sorting...
You want a random order, that's not a sorting in anyway.

Comment: In my array i have objects with keys, i want my nsarray to be sorted with the first elements being the ones with value 6   and then 5 and then 7...

Comment: Array can't have objects with keys, its uses indexes.
May be you have different structure like Array of dictionary.

Comment: NSsarray of custom objects yes.

Comment: can't help you, until you provide structure in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the for loop and manage or order object accordingly.

Create another dictionary with 5,6,7 as keys and value contains the array of object where key commandeState is the dictionary key.

Then from above dictionary create an array by appending elements.

Comment: How can I loop and order objects in an array with an order that almost seems random, first elements are the ones with 6 in their value, then the ones with 5 and then the ones with 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [notSortedArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
  if (a.value == 6) {
    return true;
  } else if (b.value == 6) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return a.value > return b.value;
  }
}];
```

Bassically is a normal asc sort, but with a rule over the "6 value".